# When click on link it $_POST image, link and title to PHP file!

Tags: php, html

So here is the basic HTML I'm using:

```
<body>
    <li>
        <img src="Chrome.jpg"/>
        <a title="Chrome" href="the.php">Visit Site</a>
    </li> 

    <li>
        <img src="IE.jpg"/>
        <a title="internet explorer" href="the.php">Visit Site</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="Mozilla.jpg"/>
        <a title="Mozilla" href="the.php">Visit Site</a>
    </li>
</body>
```

The PHP is still a mystery since I don't have the slightest clue on how to start it.

```
<?php

if($_POST = "Mozilla"){
    $someValue = "http://Mozilla.com";  
    $someValue = "Mozilla.jpg"; 
    $someValue = "Mozilla";
}

?>
```

And here is the page that will direct the user to the desired destination, it will have
the image, the title, and the link:

```
<html> 
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=<?php echo $someValue;?>">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="<?php echo $someValue;?>" />
    Please Wait While we direct you to <?php echo $someValue;?>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks confusing but I hope you get the point of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What is the question? Why do you use the same variable name for three different pieces of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not need of `$_POST` variables. Post is mostly used for form submits. Despite the fact that you could simulate it, it is not very recommended. Instead of using the POST method I'd suggest you to use the GET method via query string: `www.google.com?variable=value` retrieving variables using `$_GET['variable']; // = value`.
This is the main page.

```
<body> 
    <li>
        <img src="Chrome.jpg"/>
        <a title="Chrome" href="the.php?browser=chrome">Visit Site</a>
    </li> 

    <li>
        <img src="IE.jpg"/>
        <a title="internet explorer" href="the.php?browser=ie">Visit Site</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="Mozilla.jpg"/>
        <a title="Mozilla" href="the.php?browser=mozilla">Visit Site</a>
    </li>
</body>
```

This is `the.php`:

```
<?Php

$default_browser = 'chrome'; // change it as you want
$browser = (isset($_GET['browser'])) ? $_GET['browser'] : $default_browser;
switch ($browser) {
    case 'chrome':
        $link = // link
        $image = // image
        $title = // title
    break;
    case 'ie':
        $link = // link
        $image = // image
        $title = // title
    break;
    case 'mozilla':
        $link = // link
        $image = // image
        $title = // title
    break;
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=<?php echo $link;?>">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="<?php echo $image;?>" />
        Please Wait While we direct you to <?php echo $title;?>
    </body>
</html>
```

You have to fill `$link`, `$image` and `$title` with what you want.
Tell me if something is confusing.

Comment: Im Getting An Error do i put the links like this $link = "http://Mozilla.com" // link ?

Comment: NVM i got it thank's man i really like the code clean and simple! Thank you Again!

Comment: @donvitto, yes you have to fill the variables such as: `$link = 'http://mozilla.com';`, `$image = 'mozilla.jpg';` and `$title = 'Mozilla';`.